# (React Native) How to keep animated component in new place after initial animation

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, animation, frontend

I have a `<TextInput>` which, when the user enters anything into, will have a button appear from behind it.

This works fine using the *Animated* library from react, but each time I input text into the area, the animation "rubber bands" up and down.

My question is: How can I keep the button in place after the initial animation happens?

I still need to monitor whether the text box is empty in order to decide whether to show or hide the button.

My code:

```
import { View, TextInput, StyleSheet, Animated, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { useState } from "react";
import CurrencyInput from 'react-native-currency-input';
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

type expenseItemData = {
  item:string;
  costAndSign:string;
  cost:number | null;
}

type Props = {
    sendItem:  ({ item, cost, costAndSign }: expenseItemData) => void;
}
const AnimatedTouchable = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(TouchableOpacity);
const AddAndConfirmExpense: React.FC<Props>  = ({sendItem}) => {
    const [animation] = useState(new Animated.Value(-58));
    const [expenseValue, setExpenseValue] = useState<number>(0.00);
    const [expenseItem, setExpenseItem] = useState<string>("");
    const [expenseValueAndSign, SetExpenseValueAndSign] = useState<string>("");
    const [buttonLayoutPersistence, setButtonLayoutPersistence] = useState({
        bottom:0
    });
    const [validExpenseItem, setValidExpenseItem] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const onChangeExpenseItem = (text: string) => {
        setExpenseItem(text);
        if (text.trim().length === 0) {
            setValidExpenseItem(false);
            hideButton();
            setButtonLayoutPersistence({bottom:0})
            return;
        }
        if (validExpenseItem) {
            setButtonLayoutPersistence({bottom:-48})
            return
        };
        showButton();
        setValidExpenseItem(true);
    };

    const onButtonPress = () => {
        const newData:expenseItemData = {
            item:expenseItem,
            costAndSign:expenseValueAndSign,
            cost:expenseValue
        } 
        sendItem(newData);
    };
        
    
    const setAreaDynamicStyling = () => {
        if (validExpenseItem) {
            return {
                borderTopRightRadius:5, 
                borderTopLeftRadius:5,
                backgroundColor:"#f5f5f5"
            }
        }
        return {borderRadius:5};
    };

    const setButtonDynamicStyling = () => {
        if (!validExpenseItem) return {borderRadius:5}
        return {borderBottomLeftRadius: 5,borderBottomRightRadius:5}
    };
    const animatedStyle = {transform: [{translateY:animation}],};
    const showButton = () => {
        Animated.timing(animation, {
            toValue: -10,
            duration: 1000,
            useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start();
    }
    const hideButton = () => {
        Animated.timing(animation, {
            toValue: -58,
            duration: 500,
            useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start();
    }

    return (
        <View>
        <View style={validExpenseItem ? [styles.inputsContainer, setAreaDynamicStyling()] : [styles.inputsContainer,styles.shadowProp,setAreaDynamicStyling()]}>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.textInputArea}
                placeholder='Item'
                placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
                onChangeText={(text) => {onChangeExpenseItem(text)}}
                value={expenseItem}
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                autoCapitalize="none"
            />
            <View style={styles.verticalLine}/>
            <CurrencyInput 
                style={styles.currencyInputArea}
                value={expenseValue}
                onChangeValue={setExpenseValue}
                prefix="£"
                delimiter=","
                separator="."
                precision={2}
                minValue={0}
                onChangeText={(formattedValue) => {
                    SetExpenseValueAndSign(formattedValue)
                }}
            />
        </View>
        <AnimatedTouchable onPress={()=>{onButtonPress()}} style={[{flex:1, zIndex:-1},animatedStyle]}>
            <View style={[styles.confirmInputContainer, setButtonDynamicStyling(), buttonLayoutPersistence]}>    
            <Ionicons name="checkmark-circle-outline" size={24} color="white" />
            </View>
        </AnimatedTouchable>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    confirmInputContainer:{
        backgroundColor:"#7f96ff",
        height: 48,
        flexDirection:"row",
        paddingVertical:10,
        justifyContent:"center",
    },
    inputsContainer:{
        backgroundColor:"white",
        height: 48,
        flexDirection:"row",
        paddingVertical:10,
        marginVertical:10,
        justifyContent:"space-between",   
    },
    shadowProp: {
        shadowColor: '#353935',
        shadowOffset: {width: -2, height: 4},
        shadowOpacity: 0.2,
        shadowRadius: 4,
        
      },
    textInputArea:{
        width:"60%",
        maxWidth:"60%",
        marginLeft:20,
    },
    verticalLine:{
        height: "100%",
        width: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#909090",
        marginHorizontal:5,
        
    },
    currencyInputArea:{
        maxWidth:"20%",
        width:"20%",
        marginRight:20
        
    },

})

export default AddAndConfirmExpense;
```

#### EDIT:

I have added:

```
const [animationActive, setAnimationActive] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
        if (!animationActive && validExpenseItem) {
            setButtonLayoutPersistence({bottom:-48})
        };
        if (!animationActive && !validExpenseItem) {
            setButtonLayoutPersistence({bottom:0})
        }
    },[animationActive])
```

And changed my show and hide functions to the following:

```
    const showButton = () => {
        if (animationActive) return;
        setAnimationActive(true)
        Animated.timing(animation, {
            toValue: -10,
            duration: 500,
            useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start(
            () => {
            setAnimationActive(false)
            }
        );
    }
    const hideButton = () => {
        if (animationActive) return;
        setAnimationActive(true)
        Animated.timing(animation, {
            toValue: -58,
            duration: 500,
            useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start(
            () => {
                setAnimationActive(false)
            }
        );
    }
```

I have also changed `onChangeExpenseItem` to :

```
    const onChangeExpenseItem = (text: string) => {
        setExpenseItem(text);
        if (text.trim().length === 0) {
            setValidExpenseItem(false);
            hideButton();
            setButtonLayoutPersistence({bottom:0})

            return;
        }
        
        if (!validExpenseItem && !animationActive) {
            setValidExpenseItem(true);
            showButton();
            return
        };
    };
```

It is slightly better now, but a better solution is still needed.
[image: Clarification on behaviour]

Comment: could you add a gif for what are you trying to achieve, because this line here `when the user enters anything into, will have a button appear from behind it.` is not clear

Comment: @Hamed I can when i'm at my computer, but for now what i'm trying to achieve is similar to [apple's login page](https://appleid.apple.com/sign-in), in the sense that once you click the next button, the password box appears from the email box.

Comment: How can I keep the button in place after the initial animation happens ... which button and where u want to keep it ?

Comment: @Ahmed5G the button in the gif with the tick icon